# What does mean my English is rubbing off?

Tags: word-usage

I said let's grow together mate to a male friend who is working with me. Then the owner said " Mate? My English is rubbing off. And I don't get it. I said anything wrong or he is trying to be funny?

Comment: ***I*** don't get it. Why on earth didn't you ask ***him*** what he meant ***at the time**?*

Comment: I think your friend is  Australian and he was joking that his Australian English is infecting you.

Answer (score 4):

We say that one person's characteristic *rubs off on* another person if they begin to acquire that characteristic from being in the first person's company a lot - in the way that some coloured surfaces 'rub off' and make a mark on another surface that they touch.

Your friend meant that you were learning colloquial English expressions by working with him.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is being factual and informal. If we say that some knowledge or skill 'rubs off' one person [on someone else] then we mean that the knowledge or skill is transferred to the second person, because the two people have spent time together. You have heard him use 'mate' in conversation, and now you do it as well. It is a figure of speech. Imagine you painted something, e.g. a wooden toy, in a certain colour, then wrapped it in a white cloth and carried that around in a bag. After some time, you might unwrap the cloth and find that some of the colour has rubbed off on the cloth. So figuratively we can use 'rub off' to discuss something being transferred by association or contact.

> rub off
>
> phrasal verb with rub verb [ I or T ]
>
> informal
>
> If a quality or characteristic that someone has rubs off,
> other people begin to have it because they have been with that person
> and learned it from them:
>
> *His enthusiasm is starting to rub off on the rest of us.*

[Rub off (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rub-off)